# Display 4 Pictures in the middle

Tags: android, android-layout

Hy!

I want to have have a layout like this:

[image]

The problem is i don't know what to use:

- Gridview?
- TableLayout?
- LinearLayout with PictureViews?

The Pictures should be oriented in the middle of the screen(horicontal & vertikal)

Please add some code example in your answers.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way can do this type of layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/bg_img"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/bg_img"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/bg_img"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/bg_img"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i used this image download from here, image is too big but this was test only you can use your images just replace the background src in imageview in each or as per your requirement.

[image]

and you get the result like this way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use below linearlayout with Imageview..Main trick is hot use weight in linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```